# how to install jdk in ubuntu without an internet

Tags: jdk

Right now I don't have a working internet connection on my Ubuntu 12.10 . So is there a way to download some kinda archive or debian package and copy it to my Ubuntu and then install it ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version you want.

Openjdk is in the repositories. You can download the deb file and its dependencies from http://packages.ubuntu.com.

If you want an Oracle JDK then you must download an archive from Oracle and install it. You have good documentation here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Oracle_Java_7